# Square of even numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell, square

I am trying to write a basic function in Haskell as shown below. My aim is provide the code to square only even numbers while odd numbers will stay same. Would you please help me regarding this issue.

```
square:: Int -> Int
square x = [ x*x | x <- [1..10], mod x 2 == 0 ]
```

regards

Comment: Given the type `Int -> Int`, why is there a list involved in your proposed solution, and why don't you use the parameter `x` for anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quite straightforward answer to your question is, you can inline a `if` statment directly into your list comprehension like so:

```hs
[ if even x then x * x else x | x <- [1..10] ]
```

This is possible since `if` is an expression in Haskell, meaning it evaluates to a value, so things like this are valid:

```hs
let _ = if 1 + 1 == 2 then "foo" else "bar"
```

It can also be good to look at this problem in another direction. List comprehensions can be quite nice, but sticking an `if` within it can get pretty messy. Willem's solution of factoring out the method is great, so let's look at other ways we can leverage it with your code:

```hs
-- This is the function we're trying to implement
evenSquares :: [Int] -> [Int]

-- We could start by noting that `if` expression has a nice name,
-- which can be factored out to make things look cleaner
-- Same implementation as Willem's
evenSquares xs = [ squareIfEven x | x <- xs ] where
  squareIfEven x = if even x then x * x else x

-- List comprehensions are nice, but there's also another name for what we're doing,
-- which is mapping over a collection of values and applying a method
evenSquares xs = map squareIfEven xs where 
  squareIfEven x = if even x then x * x else x

-- Note how the `xs` is an argument to `evenSquares` and also the last argument to `map`
-- We can actually get rid of `xs` entirely via this rule:
-- https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion
evenSquares = map squareIfeven where
  squareIfEven x = if even x then x * x else x

-- This one's a bit of a stretch, but conceptually quite useful
-- The idea of 'apply a method if a condition is true' can be expressed as a method
-- which takes a predicate method, a transformation method, and a value
-- We can leverage this ourselves to make `squareIfEven` more generic too
evenSquares = map (if' even square id) where
  square x = x * x
  if' pred fst snd x = if pred x then fst x else snd x

-- There's a bunch more solutions we can try, including things like `do` notation
-- This is just an idea of how you could look at your problem
-- Pick one which makes your solution clear and concise!
```

Comment: I really appreciate your wonderful and detailed explanations. But I'm trying to learn this language for the first time and don't have any knowledge for "map and if" functions. However, your contribution will serve as guidance for my learning path.

Comment: thank you very much for the updated statement. But when I tried it like this it has been loaded but didnt't work. What is the problem you think? squareEv :: [Int] -> [Int] 
squareEv x, [ if even x then x * x else x | x <- [1..10] ]                                                                 I got this error: <interactive>:13:13: error:
    * No instance for (Num [Int]) arising from the literal `4'
    * In the first argument of `squareEven2', namely `4'
      In the expression: squareEven2 4
      In an equation for `it': it = squareEven2 4
ghci>

Comment: Ok I solved it by replacing brackets from [Int]

Comment: So the type `evenSquares :: [Int] -> [Int]` states that it expects a list of integers, and will return a list of integers. To call it, you would do something like `evenSquares [1, 2, 3]`.

Answer (score 2):

You are here *filtering*. You should determine if the number is even or odd and then square the number or not, this can be done in the yield part of the list comprehension.

But the type signature hints that you do not need to construct a list at all. You simply check if the parameter `x` is even, and if that is the case return `x*x`, otherwise return `x`:

```
square:: Int -> Int
square x = if even x then x*x else x
```

or through guards:

```
square:: Int -> Int
square x
  | even x = x*x
  | otherwise = x
```